# Display output from custom module in a panel

Tags: 7, panels

How would I output data from a custom module to be displayed in a panel pane?

Comment: http://drupal.org/files/issues/manual_drupal_panels.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend using [hook_block_info()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!block!block.api.php/function/hook_block_info/7) and [hook_block_view()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!block!block.api.php/function/hook_block_view/7) to expose your custom content in a block. This gives you Panels support + contextual links should the need for a form arise, and you can set caching settings for the block.

Comment: But no data can be sent to the code, can it ?

Comment: Certainly it can! Are you getting data from the URL (i.e. ?foo=bar) or from the database or what?

Answer (score 0):

For my part I create a function that prints or echoes what I want and I simply call it in a PhP block (by using "Add custom content" in Panels) and use PhP filter.

You can call any function defined in your module and send it args the normal way, like

`<?php myfunction(%node:nid); ?>`

Panels is very handy there, because it gives you all sorts of data to use as arguments. You can do the same with blocks and PhP filter, but without access to data.

Comment: thanks. Is this an 'official' way of doing things?

Comment: At the shop I work at, we avoid putting PHP into the database wherever possible. Sometimes it's the path of least resistance and it happens, but with version control (everything is in Git) it can prove problematic to split functionality between the codebase and the database.

Comment: Yep, but frequently the solution of getting data from URL is irrelevant... :(

Comment: Explain what you mean by getting data from the URL in your original question and I can update my answer. $_GET variables, $GLOBALS, the active menu object (i.e. a node), the current user – all of this and more is available to you.